# Allow Only Selected Domains to Access Certain Pages

Tags: php, security, apache, .htaccess

I figure this can be accomplished with htaccess but I'm not sure how. Third-party payment processors for our site has a generic response handler that determines the payment method to process. Responses from these payment processor are passed via POST/GET after a redirect from their server. This gives us the burden to ensure that the data passed to our response handler indeed originated from a valid payment processor site. How I accomplish this using htaccess? BTW, I'm using PHP if in case htaccess is not enough for the solution.

Note: This is how the response handler URL looks like

```
http://www.mydomain.com/seo-something-something-payment-callback.html?foo=bar&winnie=thefoo
```

or a POST equivalent.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the IP address is constant, you can simply create a  section in .htaccess and only allow the given IPs/subnets to access the contents, e.g.

```
<Directory "/some/dir">
Order Deny, Allow
Deny from All
Allow from 1.2.3.4
</Directory>
```

Otherwise, you could just check for $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] variable and compare with the valid address.

Comment: You could also use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] to get the location the last page call came from, however it is not completly safe, so that if someone comes to your page from google.com, you can ask the referer if that person came from there and the script will generate the corisponding form.

Comment: HTTP_REFERER is being stripped off from the Bancnet server. Maybe for security reasons.